# how to fetch distinct records from 3 tables which should contain all the values from 1 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, plsql

I have query which should fetch all the matching records from 3 tables. other records which are not common in three tables, it should union the records from first table..
EX:

```
select a.x,a.y,a.z
from table1 a,table2 b,table3 c
where a.x=b.x
and  b.x=c.x;
```

above query will fetch common records among all 3 tables.
I need to add the records to my result set which are not present in table2 or table3.

Records should come like below:

```
1 abc acd
2 xyz xzy
3 pqr prq
4 null null -- incase 4 is not present in either table2 or table3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `outer join` instead:

```
select a.x,a.y,a.z
from table1 a
   left join table2 b on a.x=b.x 
   left join table3 c on b.x=c.x;
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 0):

You state

> other records which are not common in three tables, it should union
>   the records from first table.

Then state

> I need to add the records to my result set which are not present in
>   table2 or table3.

For the first case use a full outer join which will return all rows from all tables.  For the second case use left joins which will leave out rows that have no match to table1.

Comment: Thanks @sgeddes and Joe C